# Why does the Maps application keep launching?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, google-maps

For some strange reason Google Maps launches on its own.  It doesn't launch all the way though.  It just leaves a black screen.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Try Uninstalling and re-installing it.
2. Clear the app data.
3. Might be a bug with the custom ROM (ignore if on stock).

As for WHY it is happening, could be a faulty installation IMO, but if the package was faulty, it wouldn't get installed in the first place. Anyhow, just try the above steps.